# SonarQube integration with TFS2012

Tags: sonarqube5.1

I am using SonarQube 5.1.How can i run Sonar-runner from TFS(2012) after build successful.There is a [document](https://vsarguidance.codeplex.com/downloads/get/1452516) prepared by ALM rangers about the installation of SonarQube and integration with TFS, But it targets TFS 2013.How can i integrate SonarQube with TFS 2012

Answer (score 0):

ALM Rangers' guidance should apply equally to TFS 2012, except that none was able to test it. Replace TFS 2013 version number `12.0` with 2012's, i.e. `11.0` and it should work.

If you are successful, or find some issues, please report your feedback.

Comment: I tried to integrate SonarQube with TFS 2012.But I am facing problem in setting Pre-build script path (/key:{SonarQube project key} /name:{SQ project name} /version:) and Pre-build script arguments(full path to MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe) under build process parameters. These options are not available for TFS 2012 under build process parameters. Is there anyway to set these parameters.

Comment: You need a custom build template (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551.aspx). Colin explains at http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/build-script-hooks-for-tfs-2012-builds, how to make a 2012 template similar to 2013's default one.